# Bazel build error: Expected build_bazel_rules_typescript to be version $

Tags: typescript, build, bazel

While running bazel build getting error:

```
@bazel/typescript/check_version.js:73
    throw new Error(`Expected build_bazel_rules_typescript to be version ${
    ^
Error: Expected build_bazel_rules_typescript to be version 0.21.0
```

tried **bazel clean --expunge** , cleaning node_modules and bazel_out folders with no success